# Point of completion of declaration of a variable

Tags: c, initialization, declaration, definition

The following code has variables used to initialize themselves, I have difficulty understanding when is a variable declaration completes and is some of them are illegal even though they compiles in gcc.

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = a;
    int b = (int) &b;
    int c = c ? 1 : 0;
    int d = sizeof(d);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
int a = a;
```

is UB, because you're reading an indeterminate value.

```
int b = (int) &b;
```

will compile fine, because, the variable is already allocated memory, but it is not guaranteed by the standard that an `int` will be able to hold a value of a pointer. So, technically, this also will go to UB.

```
int c = c ? 1 : 0;
```

is UB for the same reason as first one.

```
int d = sizeof(d);
```

is fine, as in this case, `sizeof` gets evaluated at compile time and the value is a compile time constant.

Comment: can you quote the relevant C standard sections too?

Comment: If the second works is implementation dependent. In general, it is a very bad idea to use anything else than `(u)intptr_t` to store a pointer in an integer.

Comment: @bare_metal I believe chapter 6.7 from C11 should answer your queries. :)

Comment: @bare_metal **Section J.2 Undefined behavior** - _An lvalue designating an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the `register` storage class is used in a context that requires the value
of the designated object, but the object is uninitialized. (6.3.2.1)._

Comment: @bare_metal Also in **Section J.2** - _Conversion to or from an integer type produces a value outside the range that can be represented (6.3.1.4)._

Answer (score 1):

This concept is better described in the C++ Standard (3.3.2 Point of declaration ) and has the same meaning in the C Standard

> 1 The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its
>   **complete declarator** (Clause 8) and **before its initializer** (if any),
>   except as noted below.

```
[ Example:
int x = 12;
{ int x = x; }
```

> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.
>   —end example ]

In the code example your showed in this declaration

```
int a = a;
```

variable a is initialized by itself. So it has indeterminate value.

This statement

```
int b = (int) &b;
```

is valid and variable `b` has an implementation-defined value.

This declaration

```
int c = c ? 1 : 0;
```

in fact is equivalent to the first declaration. Variable `c` has an indeterminate value.

This declaration

```
int d = sizeof(d);
```

is valid because the expression used in the operator `sizeof` is unevaluated.

Answer (score 1):

See **Section 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers** in the C11 specification. The scope of a variable begins just after the completion of its declarator. For the meaning of *declarator* see **Section 6.7.6 Declarators**. Note that the *initializer* (if present) comes after the *declarator*, so the variable being declared is in scope within the *initializer*. See **Section 6.7 Declarations** for the syntax of declarations, the *initializer* is part of an *init-declarator* which is defined as

```
init-declarator:
     declarator
     declarator = initializer
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
int a = a;
```

definition of `a` happens before the evaluation of `a` and the initialization. Same goes with second and fourth declarations except that first and third will invoke undefined behavior..

In case of

```
int c = c ? 1 : 0;
```

the problem is that variable `c` is used before initialization and may result in undefined behavior.